# How to inject Mocks into Spring Service

Tags: spring, junit, mockito

**Environment :**

Spring MVC 4

Junit

Mockito

**Code :**

Spring Service under test :

```
@Service("abhishekService")
public class AbhishekServiceImpl implements AbhisheskService {

    @Autowired
    private DaoOne daoOne;  
    @Autowired
    private DaoTwo daoTwo;
    @Autowired
    private DaoThree daoThree;
    @Autowired
    private DaoFour daoThree;

}
```

Junit Test :

```
public class AbhishekServiceImplTest {

    @Mock
    private DaoOne daoOne;  
    @Mock
    private DaoTwo daoTwo;
    @Mock
    private DaoThree daoThree;
    @Mock
    private UserDao userDao;

    private AbhisheskService abhisheskService;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){        

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        abhisheskService = new AbhishekServiceImpl();

    }
```

}

Issue :

1)As shown in code snippet one , the class under test uses four dependencies.

2)As shown in code snippet two , in junit test case class , all 4 dependencies are mocked using `@Mock`

3)My question is : how these four mocked objects should be injected into test class ?

4)My class under test doesn't have constructor/setter injection but field injection using `@Autowired.`

5)I don't want to use `@InjectMocks` annotation due to its dangerous behavior 
[as mentioned here](https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/mockito-why-you-should-not-use-injectmocks-annotation-to-autowire-fields/)

Can anybody please guide on this ?

Comment: Couldn't you refactor the service to have constructor injection? It's a simple thing to do.

Comment: The article that you linked yourself already contains advice on how to avoid the problem - what else do you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to test a class wrongly designed to test the behavior i.e. the properties are not accessible to be mocked. `AbhishekServiceImpl` has to provide a way to inject the mocks to the class. If you cannot access the fields then it is a clear case of wrongly designed class. Considering that the `AbhishekServiceImpl` is a class in a legacy code and you are trying to test the behaviour then you can use reflection to inject the mock objects as below:

```
DaoOne mockedDaoOne = mock(DaoOne.class);
    when(mockedDaoOne.doSomething()).thenReturn("Mocked behaviour");

    AbhishekService abhishekService = new AbhishekServiceImpl();
    Field privateField = PrivateObject.class.getDeclaredField("daoOne");

    privateField.setAccessible(true);

    privateField.set(abhishekService, mockedDaoOne);

    assertEquals("Mocked behaviour", abhishekService.doSomething());
```

Its very rare that you test behaviour of a class that you have not written yourself. Though I can imagine a use case where you have to test an external library because its author did not test it.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark the junit test with @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) and then use @ContextConfiguration to define a context which instantiates the DAOs and service and wires them together.